# How to print to screen - not in terminal window (bash)

Tags: bash, macos

I would like to print to the screen of a mac computer with bash. I don't want this to be in a terminal window, I want it to be in front of everything, right across the screen. Is this possible? All methods seem to point to print or echo, but as I mentioned before, I don't want to have it in a terminal window. Thanks!

Comment: All printing to screen seem to make reason when the output is the terminal. It is not all clear what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

Or, if you wanted more impact, you can display a *"Honking Great Message"*...

[image]

I used the example [here](https://macosxautomation.com/mavericks/libraries/examples.html) and saved this code as `alert`

```
use script "Alert Utilities"
set advancedSettings to {background color:{65535, 0, 0}, background dimensions:{1024, 90}, opacity:100}
display overlay text "Warning. Boss approaching…" duration 10 advanced settings advancedSettings with goose honk
```

Then I ran it with

```
osascript alert
```

**Original Answer**

```
osascript -e 'tell app "System Events" to display alert "How about this?"'
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in knowing when a script it done running an notification might be suitable?

```
msg="my message"
title="my title"
osascript -e 'display notification "'"$msg"'" with title "'"$title"'"'
```

Comment: not really, but thanks anyway, I will use that as well.